# how to convert value got from map to int in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
private def getInterfaceInfo(rawData: JsValue): NetworkDeviceInterfaceInfo = {
  def getTotalInterfaces(group1: JsValue): Int = {
    var count: Int = 0
    val interfacesList = group1.as[JsObject].fields.groupBy {
      case (key, value) => key.split("_", 2)(1)
    }.map {
      case (key, values) =>
        (key, values.toMap)
    }.map {
      case (key, valuesMap) =>
        val ifType = valuesMap.get(s"ifType_$key").getOrElse()
        if (ifType.toString.contains("6")) {
          count += 1
        }
    }
    return count
  }
```

//Here in code val ifType i got its value "2" i want it like 2 ...can anybody help me out from here

Comment: did you try .toInt ? You must perhaps wrap that .toInt in a Try block though!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're asking to turn a string containing an integer into an integer?

You could do

```
"2".toInt
```

provided you know it will be an integer. If however your string was "asdf".toInt this would produce an error.

As stated above you could wrap it in a Try block in case of an exception, or you could make your own function that could convert it "safely" (whatever would be usable by your program).